# How can I select only a particular row in a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a little program that just needs to read one (and only one) row from a csv file and write the column values to a series of files.  The program has three system arguments: the path to the data file, the job id (uuid), and the target row number, i.e. the row in the csv that I want to parse.  It's not working, how can I fix it?

```
import csv
import sys
import itertools

f = sys.argv[1]
uuid = sys.argv[2]
target_row = sys.argv[3]
tmpdir="/tmp/pagekicker/"
folder = tmpdir+uuid

destination1 = folder + '/csv/row.editedby'
destination3 = folder + '/csv/row.booktitle'
destination4 = folder + '/csv/row.seeds'
destination5 = folder + '/csv/row.imprint'
f = open(f, 'rb')
f1 = open(destination1, 'w')
f3 = open(destination3, 'w')
f4 = open(destination4, 'w')
f5 = open(destination5, 'w')

target_row = int(target_row)
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # creates the reader object
    for row in itertools.islice(reader,1,1):   # iterates the rows of the file in orders
            editedby = row[0] # we throw away column 2
            booktitle = row[2]
            print row[2]
            seeds = row[3]
            imprint = row[4]
            f1.write(editedby)
            f3.write(booktitle)
            f4.write(seeds)
            f5.write(imprint)
            f.close()      
            f1.close()
            f3.close()
            f4.close()
            f5.close()
finally:
    print 'done'
```

UPDATE: thanks Graham Bell for his suggested code. There are two "f5s" in the first line of his 'with' statement  My code now looks like this:

i

```
mport csv
import sys
import itertools

f = sys.argv[1]
uuid = sys.argv[2]
target_row = sys.argv[3]
tmpdir="/tmp/pagekicker/"
folder = tmpdir+uuid
# os.mkdir(folder)

destination3 = folder + '/csv/row.booktitle'
destination1 = folder + '/csv/row.editedby'
destination4 = folder + '/csv/row.seeds'
destination5 = folder + '/csv/row.imprint'

with open(f, 'rb') as f, open(destination1, 'w') as f1, open(destination3, 'w') as f3, open(destination4, 'w') as f4, open(destination5, 'w') as f5:
    target_row = int(target_row)
    try:
        reader = csv.reader(f)  # creates the reader object
        for row in itertools.islice(reader,1,1):   # iterates the rows of the file in orders
            editedby = row[0] # we throw away column 2
            booktitle = row[2]
            print row[2]
            seeds = row[3]
            imprint = row[4]
            f1.write(editedby)
            f3.write(booktitle)
            f4.write(seeds)
            f5.write(imprint)
        except
            print 'done'
```

Without the except, it generates "unexpected unindent" when I run it.  With the except, it says that the except line is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

the csv library DictReader() object has the ability to display the current line number with:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
reader.line_num
```

you could iterate through and do nothing until you reach the correct line number that you need, something like this:

```
for row in reader:
    if reader.line_num == row_you_want
        do something
```

the DictReader class also allows you to have the first row in your CSV file to be title columns, and then you can access them like so:

```
reader["title_of_column1"]
```

which might save you some work as well, also you should use the python with block when working with files like so:

```
with open(f, 'rb') as f, open(destination1, 'w') as f1, open(destination3, 'w') as f3, open(destination4, 'w') as f5, open(destination5, 'w') as f5:
    target_row = int(target_row)
    try:
        reader = csv.reader(f)  # creates the reader object
        for row in itertools.islice(reader,1,1):   # iterates the rows of the file in orders
            editedby = row[0] # we throw away column 2
            booktitle = row[2]
            print row[2]
            seeds = row[3]
            imprint = row[4]
            f1.write(editedby)
            f3.write(booktitle)
            f4.write(seeds)
            f5.write(imprint)
```

This way you don't have to worry about closing them all

Comment: Updated question above with revised code that is not working.  @graham-booth

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you count rows from 1 (rather than 0), here's a standalone function that will do it:

```
import csv
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys
import itertools

@contextmanager
def multi_file_manager(files, mode='r'):
    """ Context manager for multiple files. """
    files = [open(file, mode) for file in files]
    yield files
    for file in files:
        file.close()

# This is the standalone function
def csv_read_row(filename, n):
    """ Read and return nth row of a csv file, counting from 1. """
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        return next(itertools.islice(reader, n-1, n))

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print('usage: utility <csv filename> <uuid> <target row>')
    sys.exit(1)

tmpdir = "/tmp/pagekicker"
f = sys.argv[1]
uuid = sys.argv[2]
target_row = int(sys.argv[3])
folder = os.path.join(tmpdir, uuid)

destinations = [folder+dest for dest in ('/csv/row.editedby',
                                         '/csv/row.booktitle',
                                         '/csv/row.seeds',
                                         '/csv/row.imprint')]

with multi_file_manager(destinations, mode='w') as files:
    row = csv_read_row(f, target_row)
    #editedby, booktitle, seeds, imprint = row[0], row[2], row[3], row[4]
    for i,j in zip(range(4), (0, 2, 3, 4)):
        files[i].write(row[j]+'\n')
```

Comment: This script generates an error message: `builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/fred/pagekicker-community/scripts/bin/csv_row_reader.py", line 8
    def multi_file_manager(*files, mode='r'):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

I don't understand how the mode is defined. It looks as if it's defined as r in the function but then called as w in the script. Why isn't it just defined as 'mode'?

Comment: Sorry about that—I modified something I wrote long ago and didn't test the changes and have updated the code in my answer to address the issue.

Comment: To answer your question about how mode is defined: You can give arguments default values in the function definition by assigning a value to them using `arg=x` syntax. So in the case the files will all be opened in read-mode by default. However, when the function is actually called, the default value can be overridden by supplying a different value for it. Conversely, if a function is defined with default arguments, they can left out of calls to it in which case the defaults will be used.

Comment: ` builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/fred/pagekicker-community/scripts/bin/csv_row_reader.py", line 36, in <module>
    with multi_file_manager(destinations, mode='w') as files:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/fred/pagekicker-community/scripts/bin/csv_row_reader.py", line 10, in multi_file_manager
    files = [open(file, mode) for file in files]
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/csv/row.editedby'`  I don't get this, the /tmp/pagekicker/123/csv is writable

Comment: If the directory exists and there's no write-permissions issue, it sounds it might be attempting to open the file in read mode (although that shouldn't be the case).

Comment: `destinations = [os.path.join(folder, dest) for dest in ('/csv/row.editedby',
                                                        '/csv/row.booktitle',
                                                        '/csv/row.seeds',
                                                        '/csv/row.imprint')]
print destinations` >>> runfile('/home/fred/pagekicker-community/scripts/bin/csv_row_reader.py', args='/home/fred/scratch/1001_7.csv 123 2')
['/csv/row.editedby', '/csv/row.booktitle', '/csv/row.seeds', '/csv/row.imprint']
>>>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117961/discussion-between-fred-zimmerman-and-martineau).